# Wordpress plugin that allows tagging of pictures

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a wordpress plugin that would allow you to tag a person? I'm using a buddypress theme and I'm not sure if there's plugin that would tag a picture to a user.

I've been looking in the internet but I can't find any. Hope someone would help.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what ur looking for

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demon-image-annotation/